# Why error is showing "ArgumentException: Index out of bounds." when I get touch delta position in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate a gameObject using raycast. When I run unity editor getting the error

> ArgumentException: Index out of bounds. UnityEngine.Input.GetTouch
>   (Int32 index) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/bindings_old/common/Core/InputBindings.gen.cs:619)
>   AdjustTransform.Update () (at Assets/AdjustTransform.cs:27)

Line 27 is 
`Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;`
in the below code. What I am doing wrong here?

```
 void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,100))
    {

        Debug.Log(" GO Name "+hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }

if(  Input.touchCount == 2 && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() )
    {


            hit.collider.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -touchDeltaPosition.x * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            hit.collider.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, touchDeltaPosition.y * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);


    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `Input.touchCount`?

Comment: @mjwills...I have given it as 2.if i touch with two fingers.

Comment: It was definitely `0` if you saw that error, as per the below answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index out of bounds error. How do i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664132/index-out-of-bounds-error-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) uses an index to find the status of a specific touch. If there are no touches then it throws the `Index out of bounds` error.

Since you are calling the code in your `Update` method, it is being checked every frame, even if you haven't had any input to your game.

What you need to do is check that there are touches since the last time `Update` was called using `Input.touchCount`, then get the touch:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that I've realized with this is that every time that I put the line `Input.GetTouch(0)` outside of the if-statement like below I get an error:

```
Input.GetTouch(0);

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{

}
```

However, if I keep it *inside* the if-statement like below the error is gone:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Input.GetTouch(0);
}
```