# Index out of bounds when i keep pressing with my finger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tag "mShape" is the yellow shapes.

Game Work When :
* The ball will not create if you clicked over the yellow shape.
* Click the red space will create a ball (PointA), When I moves my finger i see path of dots as direction (PointB), When i release my finger, Ball will move.

Game Not Work When :
when i keep pressing with my finger over the yellow shape and drag with my finger the touch. I got the bug.

*I used "Log viewer" assets to detect the bug when i play in my device.

[image: CHECK BUG IMAGE]

[image: CHECK BUG2 IMAGE]

```
if (ShowDir)
{
    pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    pointB.z = Ball.transform.position.z;

    if (DirDectect)
    {

        if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 92 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 88)
        {
            AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            my_audio.Play();
            pointA.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointA.y, pointA.z);
            pointB.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointB.y, pointB.z);
            //DirDectect = false;
            Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
        }

        if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 272 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 268)
        {
            AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            my_audio.Play();
            pointA.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointA.y, pointA.z);
            pointB.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointB.y, pointB.z);
            //DirDectect = false;
            Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
        }

        if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 2 || DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 358)
        {
            AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            my_audio.Play();
            pointA.Set(pointA.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointA.z);
            pointB.Set(pointB.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointB.z);
            //DirDectect = false; 
            Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
        }

        if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 182 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 178)
        {
            AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            my_audio.Play();
            pointA.Set(pointA.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointA.z);
            pointB.Set(pointB.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointB.z);
            //DirDectect = false;
            Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
        }
    }

    if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 2 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 88 ||
        DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 92 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 178 ||
        DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 182 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 268 ||
        DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 272 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 358)
    {

        DirDectect = true;
    }

    DottedLine.DottedLine.Instance.DrawDottedLine(pointA, pointB);
}

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
    {
         Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
         RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Camera.main.transform.forward);

         if (hit.collider.tag != null)
         {
             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && hit.collider.tag != "mShape")
             {
                 pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                 MyBall = Instantiate(Ball, new Vector2(pointA.x, pointA.y), Quaternion.identity);
             }

             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && hit.collider.tag != "mShape")
             {
                 ShowDir = true;
             }

             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && hit.collider.tag != "mShape")
             {

                 if (wrapActive)
                 {
                     MyBall.AddComponent<wrap>();
                 }

                 MyBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (pointB - MyBall.transform.position).normalized * speed;

                 HintShow.SetActive(false);
                 HintBtn.interactable = false;
                 SkipBtn.interactable = false;

                 ShowDir = false;
                 DesTime = true;
             }
         }  
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("NULL");
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
           if(Input.touchCount > 0 )
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(ShowDir)
        {
            pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            pointB.z = Ball.transform.position.z;

            if (DirDectect)
            {

                if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 92 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 88)
                {
                    AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                    my_audio.Play();
                    pointA.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointA.y, pointA.z);
                    pointB.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointB.y, pointB.z);

                    Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
                }

                if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 272 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 268)
                {
                    AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                    my_audio.Play();
                    pointA.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointA.y, pointA.z);
                    pointB.Set(MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, pointB.y, pointB.z);

                    Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
                }

                if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 2 || DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 358)
                {
                    AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                    my_audio.Play();
                    pointA.Set(pointA.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointA.z);
                    pointB.Set(pointB.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointB.z);

                    Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
                }

                if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 182 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 178)
                {
                    AudioSource my_audio = GameObject.Find("SDir").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                    my_audio.Play();
                    pointA.Set(pointA.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointA.z);
                    pointB.Set(pointB.x, MyBall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y, pointB.z);

                    Invoke("DirDet", 0.7f);
                }
            }

            if (DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 2 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 88 ||
                DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 92 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 178 ||
                DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 182 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 268 ||
                DottedLine.DottedLine.angle > 272 && DottedLine.DottedLine.angle < 358)
            {

                DirDectect = true;
            }

            DottedLine.DottedLine.Instance.DrawDottedLine(pointA, pointB);

        }

            if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId)){

                Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Camera.main.transform.forward);

                 if (hit.collider.tag != null ){

                        //BEGIN
                        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && hit.collider.tag != "mShape" && MoveFalse )
                        {
                            BlockCode = false;
                            pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                            MyBall = Instantiate(Ball, new Vector2(pointA.x, pointA.y), Quaternion.identity);
                        }

                        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && hit.collider.tag == "mShape" && MoveFalse)
                        {
                           BlockCode = true;
                        }

                        if (!BlockCode)
                    {
                    //MOVE
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && hit.collider.tag != "mShape")
                    {

                        ShowDir = true;
                        mShapeClicked = false;
                        MoveFalse = false;
                        Debug.Log("MOVE");
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && hit.collider.tag == "mShape")
                    {
                        ShowDir = true;
                        mShapeClicked = true;
                        MoveFalse = false;
                        Debug.Log("OverShape");
                    }

                    //NO-MOVE
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && hit.collider.tag != "mShape")
                    {
                        ShowDir = true;
                        mShapeClicked = false;
                        MoveFalse = false;
                        Debug.Log("NoMove");
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && hit.collider.tag == "mShape")
                    {
                        ShowDir = true;
                        mShapeClicked = true;
                        MoveFalse = false;
                        Debug.Log("NoMove");
                    }

                    //END 
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                        MoveFalse = false;
                        mShapeClicked = false;
                        ShowDir = false;
                        DesTime = true;

                        Debug.Log("END");

                        if (wrapActive)
                        {
                            MyBall.AddComponent<wrap>();
                        }

                        if (!mShapeClicked)
                        {
                            MyBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (pointB - MyBall.transform.position).normalized * speed;
                        }

                        HintShow.SetActive(false);
                        HintBtn.interactable = false;
                        SkipBtn.interactable = false;



                    }

                   }
                 }

            }
        }
```

Comment: The log references BallControl's Update method. Is the code you pasted the entirety  of that method?

Comment: Hello, No :) I updated the code part. Please check again :). Thank you.

Comment: Please post messages as text, not as images. If you compile in `Debug` mode, you should get line numbers.

Comment: Hello, Touch not work in editor mode. That's why i used " Log viewer " assets to see the bugs :( ..I will add more explanation :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index out of bounds error. How do i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664132/index-out-of-bounds-error-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an "out of bounds" error when you call the function `Input.GetTouch(0)`. That means you're trying to get information about the first touch occurring when there are no touches occurring. You'll need to modify your code to first make sure that there is at least one active touch, using `Input.touchCount`

Comment: Ok, but i already did " if (Input.touchCount > 0) " {  Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); ..... } .Can you modify my script. Thank you.

Comment: But not in `pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);`, unless there's some code you didn't show.

Comment: Ok, I was really thinking about that too. Yes it can be. I will change now and reply to you with the results. Thank you :)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes right at the top of the code block, `pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);` <-- not inside `if (Input.touchCount > 0)`

Comment: Hello bro :) thank you :). I fixed my game issues. I updated the post with what i did but i'm sure i can improve more :). I will make more updates each time i improves the code.

Comment: @NexusGames No, that's not how this community works! You should probably go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Do not add the answer as edit to your question but instead mark the answer that helped to solve your specific problem as accepted. If you have another question open a new one. Question about improving working code are offtopic on StackOverflow and should rather be posted to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).